# Textbox filling repeated char to the width of the control

Tags: wpf, textbox, char, repeat

I have to implement a textblock with a predefined width and some text, and fill the rest with a certain lead chars.

Ex: the text would be "toto" and the textblock would have a with of 1.5 inches, and the lead chars would be " ."

the result would look like this:

toto . . . . . . . .

Is there any way in the textblock to tell it to repeat a text for the reminder of the with of the textblock?

Or do I have to write the code myself?

Thanks

Jean-Marc

Comment: FYI, "lead" in this context means to come before, so you actually should call them "trailing characters", since "trail" means to come behind or after.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement this yourself. `TextBlock` does support text trimming, which will automatically display an ellipsis ("...") if the text is too long to fit, but that's not going to meet your requirements.

You could use `FormattedText` to determine the width of the primary text ("toto") and then again to determine the width of the trailing text ("."). You can then do some simple math to figure out how many times the trailing text needs to be repeated.

Pseudo-code:

```
var primaryFormattedText = new FormattedText(...);
var trailingFormattedText = new FormattedText(...);
var totalWidth = this.Width;
var remainderWidth = totalWidth - primaryFormattedText.Width;
var repetitionsNeeded = remainderWidth / trailingFormattedText.Width;
```